# How to edit order without create a new order in magento 1.7

Tags: magento, edit

Is there any way to edit an order in Magento without creating a new order from Magento admin? How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you customize Magento to do otherwise, when you edit the order in admin Magento creates a new order.

Comment: is there any tutorial to do that..?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for edit order in admin: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/true-edit-orders.html

Its paid extension. You can use this and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this add-on:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/extended-orders.html

it will let you edit any order in Magneto without creating a new one.